# How to call MouseLeave and MouseEnter inside a Timer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have a picturebox on my program and I'm using MouseLeave and MouseEnter to detect when the mouse enters and leaves the picturebox. But MouseEnter and MouseLeave aren't very precise if I move my mouse very fast. I need something with more precision, so I tought about using a timer to detect when the Mouse enters and leaves the picturebox. But how can I use the MouseEnter and MouseLeave event inside that timer?

```
private: System::Void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 label1->Text = "The mouse has left the picturebox";
             }
    private: System::Void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 label1->Text = "The mouse has entered the picturebox";
                 }

    private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 //insert pictureBox1_MouseLeave event here
                 //insert pictureBox1_MouseEnter event here
             }
```

Comment: they are trigged by the timer of the window redering lib, or os. maybe just lookj if you can tweak this instead of adding your own timer

Comment: Mouse messages are generally synthesized and are generated as quickly as you can process them (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/01/55108.aspx) Note that timer messages are synthesized too (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/19/10249000.aspx) and is very unlikely to help you here (creating a high-frequency timer sounds like a bad idea anyway).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I would still like to give it a try, if someone can help me with the code.